# Crash when creating view that relies on initialized singleton

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-lifecycle

I maintain a library that's causing a crash that's confusing me.

The library provides users with a custom `View` that extends `FrameLayout`. This custom `View` accesses a singleton (also defined by the library) in its constructors:

```java
CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr);

    // Other initialization.

    mySingleton = MySingleton.getSharedInstance();
}

// Two-parameter and one-parameter constructors delegate to the three-parameter constructor above.
```

The method `MySingleton::getSharedInstance` throws an exception if the configuration method `MySingleton::initSharedInstance` has not previously been invoked:

```
private static void initSharedInstance(Application application) {
    synchronized (MySingleton.class) {
        if (sharedInstance == null) {
            sharedInstance = new MySingleton(application);
        }
    }
}

public static MySingleton getSharedInstance() {
    synchronized (MySingleton.class) {
        if (sharedInstance == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("You must call initSharedInstance before calling getSharedInstance.");
        }
    }

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

I instruct library users to call `MySingleton::initSharedInstance` in their `Application::onCreate` method, and have confirmed with the users reporting this crash that they are doing so.

Here's a sample stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.activity.ManageCamerasActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.github.stkent.amplify.prompt.DefaultLayoutPromptView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.github.stkent.amplify.prompt.DefaultLayoutPromptView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
    at android.support.v7.app.m.b(SourceFile:288)
    at android.support.v7.app.e.setContentView(SourceFile:140)
    at com.example.activity.ManageCamerasActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:232)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.github.stkent.amplify.prompt.DefaultLayoutPromptView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:966)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:843)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must call initSharedInstance before calling getSharedInstance.
    at com.github.stkent.amplify.b.a.b(SourceFile:101)
    at com.github.stkent.amplify.prompt.a.<init>(SourceFile:113)
    at com.github.stkent.amplify.prompt.DefaultLayoutPromptView.<init>(SourceFile:52)
    at com.github.stkent.amplify.prompt.DefaultLayoutPromptView.<init>(SourceFile:44)
    ... 24 more
```

Clearly, `MySingleton::getSharedInstance` is being called before `MySingleton::initSharedInstance`, i.e. the `CustomView` constructor is being invoked before `Application::onCreate`, but I have no idea how that can be the case. I thought the `Application` instance would always be fully created before any `Activity`/`Fragment`/`View` code executed.

What's going on here?

---

N.B.: if links to more specific implementation details would be useful, please comment to that effect.

Comment: Are you sure you have added your Application class in AndroidManifest?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this crash, or is this purely from [this issue](https://github.com/stkent/amplify/issues/175)? That app seems to be using multidex, and I don't know if that introduces problems with this sort of global initialization, as I avoid multidex like the plague. That app also seems to be using Kotlin, and while I would not expect that to introduce problems, `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`. The `Application` should be created before your view gets a chance to go looking for its singleton, so the question is more of why your singleton is getting misplaced.

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce this crash locally - I too have studiously avoided dealing with multidex in the past. This same crash was [previously reported](https://github.com/stkent/amplify/issues/167) as occurring in a Java app, but I don't know if that app was also using multidex (I just posted to ask). Thanks for the musings - gives me a couple more directions to investigate, and I'm glad I wasn't wrong about the _expected_ initialization order.

Comment: Apparently the other application in which this crash is observed is _not_ using multidex :/

Answer (score -1):

In getSharedInstance (Application a) do: if (instance == null) {
initSharedInstance (a); }

Comment: This won't work; `initSharedInstance` requires parameters (e.g. the `Application` instance) while `getSharedInstance` does not.

Comment: just pass the application object around or untie MySingleton from Application class. Usually extending the Application class is unnecessary and/or bad practice. Try to manage global state in a retained fragment or context independent singleton instead

Comment: If you insist on having the Application class, override its onCreate () method and init singleton in it

Comment: That's exactly what is already happening: "I instruct library users to call `MySingleton::initSharedInstance` in their `Application::onCreate` method, and have confirmed with the users reporting this crash that they are doing so."

Comment: Call init before super.onCreate ()

Comment: That seems unwise; I'm not sure what happens in `Application::onCreate`, but I'm guessing it's pretty important. Your suggestions all seems to be bandaids; what I'm looking for here is a higher-level explanation of _why_ I'm seeing this behavior in the first place.

Comment: Application.onCreate () calls entry Activities.onCreate () which in turn creates its content view, so everything you call after Application's super.onCreate happens after the view was already asked to create itself

Comment: It is not a bandaid to reorder super calls as long as you call them in the overriden method